# OAuth2::Error with doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, doorkeeper

Whenever I try to authenticate with doorkeeper provider, I always got the following error

```
invalid_grant: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client. {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."}
```

I tried with other doorkeeper clients but still have the same error

Doorkeeper client:

1. https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-devise-client.git
2. http://dev.mikamai.com/post/112508735689/oauth2-on-rails-the-client-application

Doorkeeper provider:

https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-provider-app.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by downgrading omniauth-oauth2 gem version to 1.3.1 mentioned here - https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/81

Answer (score 1):

Though downgrading to `gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'` is a confirmed to be a solution, in [Doorkeeper's Create-a-OmniAuth-strategy-for-your-provider Wiki Page](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Create-a-OmniAuth-strategy-for-your-provider) it is mentioned that in your implementation of **OmniAuth Strategy for Doorkeeper** the following method should be present:

```
  # https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/81
  def callback_url
    full_host + script_name + callback_path
  end
```

There is long discussion in the referred [omniauth-oauth2 issue #81](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/81)

I personally faced the reported error when I was trying to test my **Rails 5 Devise-based Doorkeeper Provider** by using a **Rails 5 Devise-based Client app** to allow Provider's users connect their account on my client-app.

In absence of the mentioned method in my `OmniAuth::Strategies::Doorkeeper`
on front-end Devise OmniauthCallbacksController was flashing message **Invalid Credentials** and in the client-app server logs following error was seen:

```
  Started GET "/users/auth/doorkeeper" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-22 17:45:02 +0530
  I, [2017-08-22T17:45:02.386866 #14535]  INFO -- omniauth: (doorkeeper) Request phase initiated.
  Started GET "/users/auth/doorkeeper/callback?code=1b833bcc09651f98b0424a7afb1e60bd50fdcc765daf7d499bcefb5554457187&state=c215fd707ecd71c6ad0f6b5e58fa0d2da7210d86946d41e3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-22 17:45:03 +0530
  I, [2017-08-22T17:45:03.506424 #14535]  INFO -- omniauth: (doorkeeper) Callback phase initiated.
  E, [2017-08-22T17:45:03.523737 #14535] ERROR -- omniauth: (doorkeeper) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_grant: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.
  {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."}
  Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
    Parameters: {"code"=>"1b833bcc09651f98b0424a7afb1e60bd50fdcc765daf7d499bcefb5554457187", "state"=>"c215fd707ecd71c6ad0f6b5e58fa0d2da7210d86946d41e3"}
  Redirected to http://localhost:5000/
  Completed 302 Found in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

So adding that method to the strategy can be considered as an alternate solution.

Thanks.